# In QFT, how can it be shown that the field out, ${\phi_{out}}$, is a free field if the field in, ${\phi_{in}}$, is a free field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, interactions

In the Dirac picture of QFT interacting fields, if the field in, ${\phi_{in}}$, is a free field, then I know that the field out, ${\phi_{out}}$ should also be a free field. How can this be shown? Let's assume that the in and out fields obey their respective Heisenberg equations of motion:

${
i\dot{\phi}_{in}=\left[H_{0}\left(\phi_{in},\pi_{in}\right),\phi_{in}\right]\textrm{;}\\
i\dot{\phi}_{out}=\left[H_{0}\left(\phi_{out},\pi_{out}\right),\phi_{out}\right]\textrm{.}
}$

Comment: I don't think in an interacting theory, the in/out state is a free-field state, since the field can interact with itself... If you assume $\phi_{in}$ is a free field, then you have to switch off the interaction. Then $\phi_{out}$ is obviously a free-field state...